# What is the good way to share instance object between two Activities?

Tags: android, android-service

I have two activities.
If I need to share the intent of Activity 1 which started the **service** to Activity 2 for stopping the service (because onStartCommand() returns START_STICKY hence need to use the same intent to stop the service). How should I go about it smartly.

In Activity 1

```
Intent wrapperServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext,BleWrapperService.class);
bindService(wrapperServiceIntent,mBLEWrapperServiceConnection,BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(wrapperServiceIntent);
```

In Activity 2

I need to get intent that started the service (i.e wrapperServiceIntent )

```
stopService(wrapperServiceIntent);
mContext.unbindService(mServiceConnection);
```

Comment: //to pass :
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");

Comment: @DegenSharew. Check the code

Comment: @Drim it is always recommended not to send objects across activities..

Comment: You don't need the same intent object you created to start the service...you just need an intent instance that is created to stop the service explicitly. So you would just create a new intent with the same parameters to stop the service. See tynn's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The same intent doesn't mean that you need to use the exact object you used with `startService()`. You only need to use an intent which would start the service you're running. So just don't share the intent; recreate it!